# Two processes on two CPUs -- is it possible that they complete at exactly the same moment?

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, process, cpu

This is sort of a strange question that's been bothering me lately. In our modern world of multi-core CPUs and multi-threaded operating systems, we can run many processes with true hardware concurrency. Let's say I spawn two instances of **Program A** in two separate processes at the same time. Disregarding OS-level interference which may alter the execution time for either or both processes, is it possible for both of these processes to complete at **exactly** the same moment in time? Is there any specific hardware/operating-system mechanism that may prevent this?

Now before the pedants grill me on this, I want to clarify my definition of "exactly the same moment". I'm not talking about time in the cosmic sense, only as it pertains to the operation of a computer. So if two processes complete at the same time, that means that they complete 
with a time difference that is so small, the computer cannot tell the difference.

**EDIT :** by "OS-level interference" I mean things like interrupts, various techniques to resolve resource contention that the OS may use, etc.

Comment: when you say 'is it possible for both of these processes to complete' do you mean the processes exit (in an operating system sense), or are we talking about these processes completing a task? There's a big difference. (enough that I'd probably withdraw my answer if it's the former)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, thinking about time in the "[cosmic sense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativity_of_simultaneity)" is a good way to think about [time in a distributed system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_clocks) (including multi-core systems).  Not all systems (or cores) advance their clocks at exactly the same rate, making it hard to actually tell which events happened first (going by [wall clock time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall_clock_time)).  Because of this inability to agree, systems tend to measure time by [logical clocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_clock).  Two events happen concurrently (i.e., "exactly at the same time") if they are not ordered by sharing data with each other or otherwise coordinating their execution.

Also, you need to define when exactly a process has "exited."  Thinking in Linux, is it when it prints an "exiting" message to the screen?  When it returns from  `main()`?  When it executes the `exit()` system call?  When its process state is run set to "exiting" in the kernel?  When the process's parent receives a SIGCHLD?

So getting back to your question (with a precise definition for "exactly at the same time"), the two processes can end (or do any other event) at exactly the same time **as long as nothing coordinates their exiting** (or other event).  What counts as coordination depends on your architecture and its [memory model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistency_model), so some of the "exited" conditions listed above might always be ordered at a low level or by synchronization in the OS.

You don't even need "exactly" at the same time.  Sometimes you can be close enough to *seem* concurrent.  Even on a single core with no true concurrency, two processes could appear to exit at the same time if, for instance, two child processes exited before their parent was next scheduled.  It doesn't matter which one really exited first; the parent will see that in an instant while it wasn't running, both children died.

Answer (score 3):

> So if two processes complete at the same time, that means that they complete with a time difference that is so small, the computer cannot tell the difference.

Sure, why not? Except for shared memory (and other resources, see below), they're operating independently.

> Is there any specific hardware/operating-system mechanism that may prevent this?

Anything that is a resource contention:

- memory access
- disk access
- network access
- explicit concurrency management via locks/semaphores/mutexes/etc.

---

To be more specific: these are separate CPU cores. That means they have computing circuitry implemented in separate logic circuits. From the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-core_processor):

[image]

The fact that each core can have its own memory cache means that it is quite possible for most of the computation to occur as interaction of each core with its own cache. Once you have that, it's just a matter of probability. That's not to say that algorithms take a nondeterministic amount of time, but their inputs may come from a probabilistic distribution and the amount of time it takes to run is unlikely to be completely independent of input data unless the algorithm has been carefully designed to take the same amount of time.

Comment: Haha that's my question: why not? My assumption is that this is possible. And to your second part: those things are what I meant when I reference "OS-level interference". I'll clarify in my OP

Answer (score 1):

Well I'm going to go with **I doubt it**:

- Internally any sensible OS maintains a list of running processes.
- It therefore seems sensible for us to define the moment that the process completes as the moment that it is removed from this list.
- It also strikes me as fairly unlikely (but not impossible) that a typical OS will go to the effort to construct this list in such a way that two threads can independently remove an item from this list at *exactly* the same time (processes don't terminate that frequently and removing an item from a list is relatively inexpensive - I can't see any real reason why they wouldn't just lock the entire list instead).
- Therefore for any two terminating processes A and B (where A terminates before B), there will always be a reasonably large time period (in a cosmic sense) where A has terminated and B has not.

That said it **is** of course possible to produce such a list, and so in reality it depends on the OS.

Also I don't really understand the point of this question, in particular what do you mean by

> the **computer** cannot tell the difference

In order for the **computer** to tell the difference it has to be able to check the running process table at a point where A has terminated and B has not - if the OS schedules removing process B from the process table *immediately* after process A then it could very easily be that no such code gets a chance to execute and so by some definitions it isn't possible for the computer to tell the difference - this sutation holds true even on a single core / CPU processor.

Comment: "In order for the computer to tell the difference it has to be able to check the running process table" -- no, that's in order for the *operating system* to tell the difference. If you really care when processes complete a task (and completion doesnt mean the process ends), you need some way of timing that instant of completion, which almost certainly relies on clocks + clock synchronization. Once you do that, each processor can time its own completion.

Comment: @Jason I interpreted "Process" to mean the OS concept of a process rather than some arbitrary "Processing" done by a process.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, without any OS Scheduling interference they could finish at the same time, if they don't have any resource contention (shared memory, external io, system calls). When either of them have a lock on a resource they will force the other to stall waiting for resource to free up.